# How to get values from this json in python?

Tags: python, json, django

I am currently working in python and getting some json response from API.
but after trying my best to fetch data from json, I am always getting this error, **TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str** 
here is my JSON file that I received,

```
{
  "from": 1,
  "to": 10,
  "currentPage": 1,
  "total": 72,
  "totalPages": 8,
  "queryTime": "0.023",
  "totalTime": "0.059",
  "partial": false,
  "canonicalUrl": "/v1/products(categoryPath.name=All Flat-Panel TVs)?show=sku,name,salePrice&format=json&apiKey=APIKEY",
  "products": [{
    "sku": 3813048,
    "name": "Samsung - 32\" Class (31-1/2\" Diag.) - LED - 1080p - HDTV - Black",
    "salePrice": 229.99
  }, {
    "sku": 4340402,
    "name": "Samsung - 43\" Class (42.5\" Diag.) - LED - 1080p - Smart - HDTV - Black",
    "salePrice": 429.99
  }, {
    "sku": 4380083,
    "name": "Samsung - 32\" Class (31.5\" Diag.) - LED - 1080p - Smart - HDTV - Silver",
    "salePrice": 299.99
  }, {
    "sku": 4405201,
    "name": "Samsung - 50\" Class (49.5\" Diag.) - LED - 1080p - Smart - HDTV - Black",
    "salePrice": 499.99
  }, {
    "sku": 4559300,
    "name": "VIZIO - 39\" Class (38.5\" Diag.) - LED - 720p - Smart - HDTV - Black",
    "salePrice": 269.99
  }, {
    "sku": 4562031,
    "name": "Samsung - 58\" Class (57.5\" Diag.) - LED - 1080p - Smart - HDTV - Black",
    "salePrice": 649.99
  }, {
    "sku": 4569901,
    "name": "LG - 24\" Class (23.6\" Diag.) - LED - 720p - HDTV - Black",
    "salePrice": 84.99
  }, {
    "sku": 4613600,
    "name": "Samsung - 32\" Class (31.5\" Diag.) - LED - 720p - Smart - HDTV - Black",
    "salePrice": 219.99
  }, {
    "sku": 4629257,
    "name": "Samsung - 32\" Class (31.5\" Diag.) - LED - 720p - HDTV - Black",
    "salePrice": 199.99
  }, {
    "sku": 4673800,
    "name": "Insignia™ - 24\" Class (23.6\" Diag.) - LED -720p - Smart - Roku TV - Black",
    "salePrice": 139.99
  }]
}
```

and I have tried in following ways,

```
for item in result["products"]:
    print(item["sku"])
    print(item["name"])
    print(item["salePrice"])
```

and

```
for item in result:
    print(item["products"]["sku"])
    print(item["products"]["name"])
    print(item["products"]["salePrice"])
```

Can anyone tell me please where I am wrong? Can you please share some tutorials where I can understand how to decode json properly.
thanks in advance

Comment: Do you actually have the Python dictionary you posted, or do you have a string representation of a dictionary that you did not parse?

Comment: i am getting response from here `result=bb_prod.search(query= "categoryPath.name=All%20Flat-Panel%20TVs", format="json", show="sku,name,salePrice")
`and i am using just that result. i am receiving string representation of dictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be missing to parse this json. Parse it first and then do as you are doing.

```
import json
results = json.loads(results)
for item in results['products']:
    print(item["sku"])
```